# Spring-Data JPA: modelling a graph getting 'column violates not-null' when removing edges

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a set of entities that that build some sort of graph. This is modelled by a class `Entity` with two fields modelling the relationships between entities.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "fromId")
private Set<EntityRelation> outEdges;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "toId")
private Set<EntityRelation> inEdges;
```

All outEdges are supposed to belong to the entity when it is saved, the inEdges are "inferred" from these. Problem is then after removing an out-edge I always get an error `ERROR: null value in column "fromid" violates not-null constraint` where `fromid` is a field of `EntityRelation`.

For performance reasons, I don't want to have direct relations form `Entity` to `Entity`.

To fix this, I used a new Spring-Data JPA method (in the corresponding Repository class) to explicitly remove everything an entity points to (like

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from entityrelation where fromid = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
int deleteEntityRelations(String entityId);
```

But this somehow misses the whole point, since I want JPA to take responsibility of that.

what is wrong here? I really got stuck, since all posts I could find suggest that it should simply work with `orphan-delete`.

In the SQL-Trace you can see that an `org.hibernate.SQL - update EntityRelation set fromId=null where fromId=? and id=?` is issued automatically (which then triggers the error).

thanks and regards
fricke

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of hibernate. In certain scenarios (and you found one of them) it violates constraints on foreign key relations. There are various options (but I'm afraid you might not like any of them)

- remove the constraint. I know, I know ..
- make the [constraint deferred](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2934). Not sure if this feature is available in other databases but Oracle.
- limit the expectations to JPA. Seriously, it looks like you expecting more from it then it will give you. I highly recommend [reading this article](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) before proceeding with any project using any kind of ORM.

Comment: Hi Jens, first thanks, I was worried that it actually is such an ORM-thing - I guess I'm going to do it all by hand, drop the members that represent the edges and treat them as real entities (no declarative lifecycle). This will make it less nice but much more controllable == I will tune down my expections about JPA then.

Comment: oh, forgot to ask for the reason: do you know where it breaks exactly? is it the treatment of relations as proper entities (and thereby not giving them their own proper lifecycle)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know and currently can't find the specifics when exactly this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that even though setting `hbm2ddl.auto` to `UPDATE`, it doesn't remove the not-null type constrains when the `nullable` in entity is set to `FALSE`. I would suggest that check the history of the class for any changes to entity relationship or column mapping for nullable constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for the solution, `updatable=false` in the `JoinCoulum` annotation fixed this problem for me

```
@JoinColumn(name = "fromId", updatable = false)
```